# Setting PHP format in Sublime 3

Tags: php, configuration, sublimetext3, php-extension

I am using Sublime 3 and just started working with PHP. My problem is that the PHP file is showing up as an HTML. When I save it as index.php and try to view it in the MAMP server, it won't work. I am assuming it's because Sublime 3 is not recognizing this file as PHP but HTML. Can you please help with me configure the HTML to PHP.Thanks

Comment: How do you try to view it with your MAMP server? Which URL do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try clicking on the bottom right most button on Sublime Text then pick your language[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the language indicator in the bottom-right corner in sublime's window and select the correct language. For me, changeing from pure php to html doesn't do anything for syntax coloring.